# It Gives NaN instead of Content of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

This is a basic JavaScript code to calculate "tips" for a given value. Am I doing anything wrong here? It is giving me `null` arrays or `NaN` instead of my array content.

```js
var john = {

  fullName: 'john smith',
  bills: [124, 48, 32, 268, 180, 42],

  calcTips: function () {
    this.tips = [0];
    this.finalvalue = [0];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i += 1) {
      var percentage;

      if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
        percentage: .2;
      }
      else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200) {
        percentage: .15;
      }
      else {
        percentage: .1;
      }

      this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * percentage;
      this.finalvalue[i] = this.bills[i] + this.bills[i] * percentage;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking, but all those `percentage: value;` lines will do nothing, and I expect you meant `percentage = value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `percentage = value` instead of those `:`

```
var john = {
  fullName: 'john smith',
  bills: [124, 48, 32, 268, 180, 42],


  calcTips: function() {

      this.tips = [0];
      this.finalvalue = [0];

  for ( var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i+= 1 ) { 
      var percentage = 0;

      if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
          percentage= .2;
      } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200 ) {

          percentage= .15; 
      }

          else {
          percentage= .1;
      }

      this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * percentage ;
      this.finalvalue[i] = this.bills[i] + this.bills[i] * percentage;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that there are already values within the `tips` array equal to the number of values within the `bills` array, and updates the corresponding value within `tips` (incorrectly, I might add. Covered later).

However since you initialized `tips` with only one value of 0, the loop doesn't have anything to update past the first iteration.

Instead, I would recommend:

```js
var john = {
    fullName: 'john smith',
    bills: [124, 48, 32, 268, 180, 42],

    calcTips: function() {

        /* I'm assuming you initialized these with one value of 0 because you're doing 
        a calculation later using these, so we'll leave them be */
        this.tips = [0];
        this.finalvalue = [0];

        for ( var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i+= 1 ) { 
            var percentage;
            /* Reassigning variables requires the equals sign (=) rather than 
            a colon (:) */

            if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
               percentage = .2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] < 200 ) {
                percentage = .15; 
            } else {
                percentage = .1;
            }

            /* If i is 0, only update the first value of tips (using splice()), past 
            that, push in a new value */
            if (i === 0) {
               this.tips.splice(i, 1, this.bills[i] * percentage ;
            } else {
                this.tips.push(this.bills[i] * percentage);
            } 

            this.finalvalue[i] = this.bills[i] + this.bills[i] * percentage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out the root issue are the `percentage:` lines. changing those to variable assignments `percentage = 0.2;` would fix it.

You might be asking yourself "Why didn't this throw errors?".

This syntax is used to define a "label". A labels is used to identify statements that use `break` or `continue`. Basically a way to identify a loop, allowing you to name which loop you're specifically breaking or continuing. [MDN has some good use examples for labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Examples). Though rarely used, it's something to have in your back pocket :)